# Как скрыть периодически всплывающий элемент?

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка, которая должна быть скрыта, при этом, что бы была возможность её нажимать через кнопку.

При запуске приложения я её скрываю при помощи

```
document.querySelector(".test").classList.add('hidden');
```

Но когда она нажимается кнопкой, то снова сплывает, тут я использовал тоже самое

```
function ButtonClick(){
    document.querySelector(".test").click();
    document.querySelector(".test").classList.add('hidden');
}
```

Но при переходе из этой ссылки куда то в другой раздел, или например, кнопкой назад - она снова всплывает. В общем, полагаю, тут нужно что то делать через EventListener? Или нет?  (Я пока что мало чего умею).

В общем, покажите пожалуйста, как.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".test").style.display="none";
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, это же мой вопрос. Я сам сделал то, что нужно. Пояснение уже в описании вопроса)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно скрыть через *CSS*

```js
// Это чисто для показа, что клик работае
document.querySelector(".test").addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Был клик!');
})

function ButtonClick(){
    document.querySelector(".test").click();    
}

ButtonClick();
```

```css
.test {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="test">ХЕ-ХЕ-ХЕ</button>
```

Comment: В моём случае, это похоже не работает. Если на конкретный элемент

`.main-navBar-entryPoints a.link-subtle.main-navBar-navBarLink:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
}`
то не скрывает вообще, а если на что то, что уже есть - то скрывает и другие тоже.

Comment: То есть, я хочу сказать, что css всего блока, и соответственно скрывает его весь, а не одну, нужную ссылку

Comment: Я не ясновидящий. Я не вижу что вы делаете у себя там в коде........а  "Если на конкретный элемент  то не скрывает вообще" --- бессмыслица. Некорректно заданный селектор  скорее всего.

Comment: Код который я предлагаю - рабочий. Ваше предположение ни на чём не основано. Без конкретного кода, что у вас есть и что конкретно делаете в нём и описании что происходит непосредственно на нём - я не смогу помочь. Все эти рассуждения сейчас будут ни о чём.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Держу пари, что он переходит на другую страницу, на которой есть такая же ссылка.

Comment: @Igor можете ещё тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1287674/191482  поугадывать)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не, не буду. Я уже поставил минус и проголосовал за закрытие.

Comment: Молодцы, ребят. Спасибо за помощь. Вместо обучения, разъяснения тому, кто не понимает - лучше поставить минус, и проголосовать за закрытие. Это же не супер интересный вопрос от человека сидящего на заплате в 400к. А на вопрос я ещё и конкурс потом повешу, что бы снобы пошли в Икею за новыми стульями)

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 для начала научитесь чётко описывать свою проблему. Сейчас всё что написано - понятно только вам самим.

Comment: Я что-то пропустил? За что обидели Икею?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В том то и дело, вы видите проблему там, где её нет. Я ни разу не создавал вопрос "Вот у меня не получается это и это, как решить". Я уже знаю решение, мне нужно лишь его превратить в код, и грамотно присоединить к тому коду, что есть. Я не писал "Как скрыть что то там", я уже знаю, как это скрыть. Для ответа на вопрос информации уже более чем достаточно, и уже делая что то ещё - я буду опираться на ответ, делать по его примеру. Так и работает обучение, а не "Вот проблема, вот код, решайте"

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 "мне нужно забить микроскопом гвоздь, как сделать так, чтобы микроскоп каждый раз при ударе не разбивался" - это **НЕ** "я знаю, как сделать",  это - глупость несусветная. И тот, кто даст ответ "купите на АЛИ подешёвке за рубль мешок" - это не решение проблемы, а только усугбление. Так, как раз, не работает обучение. Обучение - когда другому не дают глаза вилкой выкалывать, а не дают к вилке ещё удобный молоток, чтоб быстрее вогнать себе

Comment: Но дело житейское

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ребенок учится ходить, набивая шишки.

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 Тут никто не обязан Вас обучать. Вы не можете вопрос по-человечески сформулировать, но "уже знаете решение". Может быть все-таки не знаете?